# Creating T-Sql Jobs under shared hosting?

Tags: asp.net, .net, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, jobs

I have re seller `shared hosting` plan where `Sql2008 Express R2` is installed. I want to `create a job` that will execute every midnight that is `00:00:00 hrs` and `move data from one table to another`.

I haven't created any jobs earlier, i am quite naive. I want if I can create a job in similar fashion to `Stored procedures` , for the same.

Comment: Are you asking how to create a scheduled job, or how to move data from one table to another using SQL? It's possible that your hosting provider doesn't allow you to create scheduled jobs, so I suggest that you clarify that point first.

Comment: @Pondlife obviously to create a scheduled job on Sql Server.And shared hosting generally have limited accessibility. Like Select, Insert, Update, Delete, Create,Drop, Alter and Truncate etc. Basically end user level DML queries. Not DBA level

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why I suggested that you clarify your question. It isn't clear if you're asking "how do I create a scheduled job on a hosted SQL Server without having access to SQL Agent?", or "how do I copy data from one table to another?". Or both.

Answer (score 0):

If the tables are on the same SQL Server, here is a sample stored procedure that will copy data. But you need to think about whether this will copy duplicates over or not, do you want a moving window etc.

```
CREATE PROC DB.dbo.p_CopyTable
AS
INSERT INTO DB1.dbo.Table1 (
   Column1,
   Column2,
   Column3,
   Column4
)
SELECT       
   Column1,
   Column2,
   Column3,
   Column4
FROM DB2.dbo.Table2
```

There are a lot if things you have to fill in here, like the source and target database, schema, table, columns. You have to know whether you want to not copy over data that is already there etc. There are a lot of questions to answer but this gives us a starting point.

So start with that and post back questions. Once you have stored proc that does what you want it's trivial to create a job to call it.

Comment: Open SQL Server Management Studio, go to SQL Server Agent, ensure it is started, right click jobs folder, New Job.... its pretty self explanatory from there.

Comment: If you don't have sufficient access to do this you'll need to find another scheduler on the SQL Server, but your hosts will have stopped access for a reason - they don't want scheduled jobs on the server.